# (Node.js & React.js) How to remove/show different buttons after logging in successfully?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, I am trying to make a simple login page with React.js and Node.js connected to Firebase, I think I have successfully authenticated and connected both but I have a problem after successfully logging in. I want to add or remove new buttons after being successfully logged in. I have no idea how to do that, and I tried to search for it a lot but with no avail.

Here's my server.js code for login:

```
app.post('/api/login',  function(req, res) 
{
   var success = false;
   var email = req.body.email;
   var password = req.body.password;
   console.log(email);
   console.log(password);
   Firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, String (md5(password)).valueOf())
.then(function(userData)
{
    console.log("Authenticating...");
    usersRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once("child_added", function(snapshot)
    {
        var newPost = snapshot.val();

        jwt.sign(newPost.id, "secretKey", (error,token) =>
        {
        console.log("Successfully logged in");
        res.send({token: token, success: true });
        });
    }); 
})
.catch(function(error)
{
    console.log("Error logging in: Invalid username/password");
    res.status(401).send({"Error":"Error logging in: Invalid username/password ", auth: false, token: null });
});
});
```

This works perfectly fine when I launch it on my client side which looks like this (App.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

 }
  render() {
  return (
<div className="App-header">
    <h2>Homepage</h2>

  <form id="login_div" action="/api/login" method="post" class="main-div">
   <div>
       <label for="email">Email: </label>
       <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></input>
       <label for="password">Password: </label>
       <input type="password" id="password" name="password"></input>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
  </form>
</div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

These codes run fine, but then it shows a white page with the right token and success status. Is there a way to control my login page before and after the login?

Comment: Your React app `shows a white page with the right token and success status` because that is what you do when a user has been authenticated in your Node.js app. In your React app, when you see that a  user has bee authenticated you can render some other page to let the user know that he/she has been authenticated and show them some other information based on that.

Comment: And if you want to show buttons to the user after he/she has logged in then you can keep a list of button you want to show and send appropriate booleans for those buttons from your Node.js app. Like you can send a button which takes you to the admin panel given a user is an admin else give them some other button.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do hence why I passed in Success boolean, but I don't know how to use that boolean value in React.js inside render for example.

Answer (score 0):

> These codes run fine, but then it shows a white page with the right
>   token and success status. Is there a way to control my login page
>   before and after the login?

Of course it is, but your are responding to login with the token and the success yourself at this line:

```
res.send({token: token, success: true });
```

This line responds with a json to the successfull requests to '/api/login', which is a common response format for an API request but the way you implemented your form at App.js you need to respond with an html document or at least redirect. Your are misunderstanding concepts as the form in your App.js expects a synchronous response , when the approach you should use for making a request to 'api/login' is an ajax/asynchronous call.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I was planning on using the success boolean in my client_side but I have no idea how I can do that in the render part.